# What's wrong with this use of redirection?

Tags: io-redirection

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J} ; do

     echo     "$i
               $i
               $i
               $i 
               $i
               $i
               $i
               $i"
    cat > ~/Desktop/$i.txt                    
done
```

I want to make 9 text files, each showing me one letter repeated 8 times. e.g. A.txt should have the letter A 8 times in a column)
If I run the script without the `cat`, it indeed shows me 8 times the A letter, then 8 times the B, C, etc. When inserting the `cat` statement, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cat is expecting an input, but echo command isn't redirected to cat.

Comment: ergo: just leave out the `cat` statement and put the echo statement and the redirection operator (`>`) into a single line.

Comment: like this: `echo "$i  $i  $i  $i   $i  $i   $i  $i" > ~/Desktop/$i.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're two independent commands.

```
echo something
cat > somewhere
```

You can use pipe to pass the stdout to stdin:

```
echo something | cat > somewhere
```

Comment: While he is trying to use it and I understand why you have it in your answer, It may also be useful to point out that `cat` is unnecessary in this scenario. i.e. `echo something > somewhere`

Comment: He already wrote that without cat command it works as he expected.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this would be a double for loop as follow:

```
for f in {A..J}; do for ((i=0;i<8;i++)); do printf '%s\n' "$f" >> "$f"; done; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash sequences for the loop and clever use of printf to repeat characters:

```sh
for i in {A..J};do printf "$i%.0s\n" {0..7} > ~/Desktop/$i.txt;done
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Ipor Sircer* pointed out you are just missing a pipe between your `echo` and `cat`.  Another solution would be to use `yes` to repeat the same text of multiple lines and `head` instead of `cat` to limit the number of lines, e.g.

```sh
for i in {A..J}
do
   yes -- "$i" | head -8 >  ~/Desktop/"$i".txt
done
```